# Expand node not calling callback

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am testing my ExtJs App with Jasmine. So there are no views involved.

I want to expand several nodes, but first my root node. But even expanding that node fails.

I create my TreeStore, then:

Code:

```
// oStore is my treestore, everything OK
// Here, I also tried calling oStore.load(); see below

var oNode = oStore.getNodeById( 'root' );

// oNode.isExpanded() says false
// oNode.hasChildNodes() says false

oNode.expand(false, function(oChildren) {
    // it never gets here
    console.log( "hello?");
});
```

My listener for `load` gets called, but the listener for `beforeexpand` does not get called.

If I call `oStore.load()` at the beginning after store creation, then when the on `load` listener gets called it says, `oNode.childNodes.length` has 3 children...

1. So why is `expand()`'s callback not called? How can I get that node to expand?
2. Why are the children of the node already loaded when calling `oStore.load()`? After that `expand()` is also not fired.

---

EDIT:

Starting my root node with `expanded: true` makes my store collapse correctly on `collapse()`, but after it `expand()` does nothing.

```
oNode.collapse(false, function() {
   console.log( "collapse()" ); // works, but expand() afterwards does not
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I need to wait for the store to get loaded. Is is a Jasmine issue:

```
runs( function() {
         oStore.on( 'load', function() {
            bStoreLoaded = true;
         });
      });

waitsFor( function() {
         return bStoreLoaded; 
      }, " store to be loaded", 5000 );

runs( function() {
         oNode.expand(false, function( aoChildren ) {
            aoChildrenRoot = aoChildren;
            bRootExpanded = true;
         });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some convoluted logic in the source to tell the node whether or not it needs to expand or be expandable. Take a look at the code below that I ended up resorting to when I tried to manipulate the tree programmatically:

```
if (!parentNode.isExpanded() && !parentNode.isLeaf()) {
    parentNode.expand(false, function () {// deal with open or closed paths
        console.log('expanded parent to pick up new item');                 
    });
} else {
    parentNode.callStore('suspendAutoSync');
    if (parentNode.isLeaf()) {         // Parts that are leafs
        parentNode.set("leaf", false);  //must be set to work properly
        parentNode.appendChild(newPart);
        parentNode.expand(); //expand to show newly created child
    } else {
        parentNode.insertChild(0, newPart);
    }
    parentNode.callStore('resumeAutoSync');
}
```